# Scope of Popup and InteractionRequest in Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I need clarification on when to use Pop-up, InteractionRequest. Here is my scenario.

I have left side navigation view which displays the Folder's in tree format (as same as Windows Directory). I should allow the user to Add, Rename and Remove the directory by using context menu. For Add and Rename operation, it should popup a window with "TextBox" for user input and should have "Save" and "Cancel" button. For Remove option, if should ask for confirmation.

What should i do for Add/Rename operation?

1. Create simple Window (with user input TextBox , Save and Cancel Button) without ViewModel. Save and Cancel Button click will set the DialogResult flag and close the window.
2. Create simple Window (with user input TextBox , Save and Cancel Button) with ViewModel.
   Save and Cancel button click will be handled in ViewModel (This look bit tedious since very limited code).
3. Is there any alternative way to handle this?

What should i do for Remove Operation?

1. I will go for InteractionRequest
2. I will go for Customized Window (Dialog) which will be called as like MessageBox, without popup or InteractionRequest(ie from view model => MyMessageBox.Show(.....) == Dialog.Ok..

please give me the right solution.

Comment: I want this question to have all the information about Interaction Request and Pop-Up.I spent lots of time on where to use Interaction Request and Pop-Up and where should not.

Comment: Well, I'll do little study and update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Since your Popup is so small, I would actually create a DataTemplate inside your current View and just bind the Add/Rename/Remove commands to the same ViewModel.

I like using [my own custom Popup](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/), because I've had many issues with WPF's popup's in the past. It is generally used like this:

```
<Grid Name="RootPanel">

    <DockPanel>
        <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
        // <!-- Other Window Content -->
    </DockPanel>

    <local:PopupPanel
        local:PopupPanel.PopupParent="{Binding ElementName=RootPanel}"
        local:PopupPanel.IsPopupVisible="{Binding IsPopupVisible}"

        local:PopupPanel.BackgroundOpacity=".5"
        local:PopupPanel.PopupEnterKeyCommand="{Binding SaveCommand}"
        local:PopupPanel.PopupEscapeKeyCommand="{Binding CancelCommand}">

        // Put whatever you want for Popup Content here

        // Usually I have a property in my ViewModel for PopupContent, and 
        // will put a ContentControl here that uses a different ContentTemplate 
        // based on what type of object is in PopupContent
    </local:PopupPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: 1. Will it work for TextBox user input? 2. Why not custom MessageBox like MyMessageBox.Show(..) or IMessageBox.Show(..) so that it allow me to change the message box style on fly.

Comment: @Mohanavel 1. Yes. 2. Sure you can create your own custom `MessageBox` with a `.Show()` method, but if you want to modify the content of the dialog box, then I find it easier to just use a Popup

Comment: Can you give me the URL/Sample site which holds the POP-UP or Interaction request with user input TextBox? and i want this question to have all the information about Interaction Request and Pop-Up.I spent lots of time on where to use Interaction Request and Pop-Up and where should not.

Comment: @Mohanavel I never use Interaction Request, or WPF's built-in Popups so I don't have any sites about those bookmarked. You should be able to find some pretty easily with Google though.